# Lozad lazy load with v-for in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, lazy-loading

I'm using [lozad.js](https://apoorv.pro/lozad.js/) for lazy loading my images. In my vue.js project I have 
made a custom component that's globally registered it looks basically like this:

```
<template>
    <img :alt="alt" :data-src="lazySrc" />
</template>

<script>
import lozad from 'lozad';

export default {
    props: {
        lazySrc: {
            type: String,
            default: null,
        },

        alt: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        const observer = lozad(this.$el);
        observer.observe();
    },
};
</script>
```

When I try this in a `.html` file:

```
 @foreach($recommendedFriends as $friend)
    <a href="{{ route('profile.show', $friend->slug) }}">
        <lozad class="lozad bg-cover bg-gray-200 border-4 border-white w-20 h-20 rounded-full shadow-lg z-50 m-2 zoom"
               lazy-src="{{ $friend->thumb_image }}">
        </lozad>
    </a>
@endforeach
```

The images are being lazy loaded and it works great! But when I try it in a `.vue` file:

```
<div v-for="breed in breeds">
    <lozad class="lozad rounded-lg"
           :lazy-src="breed.full_overview_image">
    </lozad>
</div>
```

Nothing is being lazy loaded. I don't get an error and the images do show up but they are not lazy loaded.

How can I fix this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but the lib is using `data-src="image.png"` to get the image, I'm not seeing where you're defining it to pick up on `lazy-src="image.png"`, its not in the docs either.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry forgot the template in my question. I have changed this now in my question.

Comment: I see it now, though its missing the `lozad` class in side the component, the `<lozad class="lozad rounded-lg"` will be placed on a `<div class="lozad rounded-lg"` when rendered

Comment: Thx, but when I change that it's still not lazy loading.